# Building dictionaries in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a data frame that is need to convert to a dictionary. I iterate over the rows in a loop, but the output is not as expected since there may be more than one "box" and "score" for each key.

```
pred_boxes = {}
for x, row in df.iterrows():
   l = [row['px1'], row['px2'], row['py1'], row['py2']]
   p = ['scores'] 

   boxes = {'boxes': l, 'scores': p}
   previous_values = pred_boxes.get(row['img_name'], [])
   previous_values.append(boxes)
   pred_boxes[row['img_name']] = previous_values
```

The result i get is as follows:

```
pred_boxes={'img_name':[{'boxes':[px1_1, px2_1, py1_1, py2_1], 'scores': [scores_1]},{'boxes':[px1_2, px2_2, py1_2, py2_2], 'scores': [scores_2]}]
```

The result I want is:

```
pred_boxes={'img_name':{'boxes':[[px1_1, px2_1, py1_1, py2_1],[px1_2, px2_2, py1_2, py2_2]], 'scores': [scores_1, scores_2]}
```

I guess i have to create a loop within the loop for each img_name (which is the key) but I have no clue how to.

Would greatly appriciate the help if anybody have a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
previous_values = pred_boxes.get(row['image_name', [])
previous_values.append(boxes)
```

to

```
previous_values = pred_boxes.get(row['image_name', {'boxes':[], 'scores':[]})
previous_values['boxes'].append( l )
previous_values['scores'].append( p )
```

You don't need to create the "boxes" dict at all.